# Instant search using jQuery is giving all the fields if nothing is typed in search box

Tags: php, jquery

This is the PHP code of my main search section.
This search is working fine except in one case: When nothing is typed in the search box, it returns all  values from the table.
How can I fix that?

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","0392") or die("Could not connect");
    mysql_select_db("emm") or die("could not connect");
    $output="";
    if(isset($_POST['searchVal'])){
      $searchq = $_POST['searchVal'];
      $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

      $query=mysql_query("select name, code from employee_table where name LIKE     '%$searchq%' or code LIKE '%$searchq%'");
      $count = mysql_num_rows($query);

      if($count == 0){
        $output='No Matching Results Found !!';
      }
      else{
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){            
          $name = $row['name'];
          $code= $row['code'];

          $output.="<a href='altprofile.php?cod=".$code."'><div class='col-md-3'><input type='text' name='nam' disabled='disabled' value='".$name."'></input></div></a> ";
        }
      }
    }
    echo($output);
?>
```

Comment: jquery part i have not show'd . Please tell if it is required

Comment: i thin k you need to add a if check condition..
if($searchq=="") then dont go into further steps

Comment: I tried the same condition but didn't worked...

Comment: I dont know how you did that but its very simple and should worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
if(isset($_POST['searchVal']) && !empty($_POST['searchVal'])){

// DO code

}else{
  echo "no results";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 ...
 if(isset($_POST['searchVal']) && $_POST['searchVal'] != ''){
   $searchq = $_POST['searchVal'];
   $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

   $query=mysql_query("select name, code from employee_table where name LIKE     '%$searchq%' or code LIKE '%$searchq%'");
   $count = mysql_num_rows($query);

   if($count == 0){
     $output='No Matching Results Found !!';
   }
   else{
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
       $name = $row['name'];
       $code= $row['code'];

       $output.="<a href='altprofile.php?cod=".$code."'><div class='col-md-`enter code here`3'>`enter code here`<input type='text' name='nam' `enter code here`disabled='disabled' value='".$name."'></input></div></a> ";
     }
  }
}
...
```

Note: Don't use mysql use mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following two things,change if condition as

```
//checks value is not empty
if(isset($_POST['searchVal']) && !empty($_POST['searchVal']))
{
  //all your stuff
}
else
{
echo "No results"
}
```